# Pygame 1.9.3: Adding sprite (without class) to a group

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

So ok, I have certain things in my game (player, boss, levelGoal...) that only need exist in one instance at any given time, and thus I would like to simplify my code by letting these things be manually-declared sprites--rather than first existing as Classes with the need to be instantiated into objects.

(Many would say it's best to group everything into classes anyway, but whether or not I agree with that--it'd certainly be useful to know a way around this just in case.)

I would like to have the sprites in groups though, for purposes of hit-detection (and being drawn onto the screen). I'm having an issue with this, however. I thought this would be pretty simple to make an isolated, "classless" sprite and add it to a list.

```
bloobList = pygame.sprite.Group()

blooby = pygame.sprite.Sprite

blooby.image = pygame.Surface([200,200])
blooby.image.fill([0,0,0])
blooby.rect = blooby.image.get_rect()

bloobList.add(blooby)
```

When running this however, the application crashes upon launching. My IDE opens up sprite.py from the Pygame library, takes me to line 378 and tells me:

```
builtins.TypeError: add_internal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group'
```

I've googled around looking for what this means and found no answers. To check myself, I wrote up a class+object+group adding scenario in the exact same program:

```
moochList = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Mooch(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([200,200])
        self.image.fill([0,0,0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

stootch = Mooch()

moochList.add(stootch)
```

And this one worked perfectly as usual. I checked Pygame.org's documentation and I don't think it specifically said a sprite must be an object spawned from a class in order to be added to a group, but it didn't specifically say "classless" sprites are allowed either.

I'm brand new to Pygame mind you, so I expect to realize I was missing something very obvious here, but what leads me to assume that classless sprites should be allowed into groups is that the group.add function *only* concerns the specific sprite named and the group itself--with no mention of the class the sprite belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you try to add the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class to the group instead of an instance. With added parentheses, to create an instance/object, it should work correctly:

```
blooby = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
```